# vbscript code to delete a row in a csv file where cell is empty

Tags: csv, vbscript, row

I have a csv file that I need to have converted to an xlsx file (not a problem)...in the process of doing that I format my data. I want to delete all rows where I have an empty cell. Column C had text data and Column D has numeric data.

I have tried :
If (.Sheets(1).Columns.Cells("D")) = "" Then
msgbox("HI")
End If

I've tried .text as well as .value I can't seem to get into the actual cells to determine if it's empty so as to delete the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a little more structure to achieve your goal.  You can't check every cell in Column D just by using `.Cells("D") = ""` as the `Cells` expects both row and column indicators to be provided.

Perhaps you could try looping over your data in Column C and/or D and where there's an empty cell, delete the whole row.

```
Const xlUp = -4162    ' Excel variables are not defined in vbscript
Dim oBook : Set oBook = ThisWorkbook
Dim oSheet : Set oSheet = oBook.Sheets(1)
Dim iLastRow, iRow
iLastRow = oSheet.Cells(oSheet.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
For iRow = iLastRow to 2 Step -1 'assumes a header row otherwise use 1 instead of 2
    If oSheet.Range("C" & iRow) = "" Then
        oSheet.Range("C" & iRow).EntireRow.Delete ' delete row if blank
    End If
Next
```

Edit after comment:
Changed the loop to run from `iLastRow` to 2 instead of 2 to `iLastRow`.  When deleting rows, you should always move from the bottom up, as when you delete a row, the next one jumps up and is then skipped over!

Comment: Thanks Dave.  I was trying to keep things simple, so I appreciate the additional structure. So originally I wasn't getting into my if statement, now I am, however the code is not deleting every row that has an empty cell. It's doing about every other and I don't see any reason why. Any ideas? On a side note it isn't deleting valid rows...:-)

Comment: @okmred Yep, I can see what's going on - I've modified the answer and added an explanation - see if that helps out...

Comment: That was it exactly, thanks so much. I appreciate the help. All the best!!